# Getting syntactical error in Hive for query to create table using left outer join

Tags: mysql, hiveql

```
create table db_db.result_av1 as
(select distinct user_name 
 from            movies.user_activity a
 left outer join (select  activity_count as result
                  from    movies.user_activity
                  where   user_activity like "%gz%")
) d
(on a.user_name=d.user_name)
where a.date between '2015-05-10' and '2015-08-04'
and   substr(user_name,1,24) is Not null
limit 5;
```

getting error

> error while compiling statement: failed:
>   parseexception line 9:0 missing eof at '(' near 'd'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parentheses are not placed right. Try this:

```
create table db_db.result_av1 as
 select distinct user_name 
 from            movies.user_activity a
 left outer join (select  activity_count as result
                  from    movies.user_activity
                  where   user_activity like "%gz%") d
              on a.user_name=d.user_name
 where a.date between '2015-05-10' and '2015-08-04'
 and   substr(user_name,1,24) is Not null
 limit 5;
```

Comment: still giving error "error while compiling statement: failed: parseexception line 2:0 cannot recognize input near '(' 'select' 'distinct' in select clause"

Comment: Have you tried to remove the offending parentheses (the first opening and last closing)?